# Window created with WINAPI is not drawing objects. What's the problem?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I have my window file (`Window.h`):

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

class Window
{
private:
    HWND hWnd;
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    bool running = true;
    const char* ID = "WINAPI_JVM64";
public:
    Window()
    {
        init();
    }

    virtual void draw(Gdiplus::Graphics*) = 0;

    void init()
    {
        hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        WNDCLASS wc;

        wc = {};
        wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = MessageHandler;
        wc.hInstance = hInstance;
        wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
        wc.lpszClassName = ID;

        assert(RegisterClass(&wc));

        hWnd = CreateWindow(ID, "Title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                       200, 200, 400, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

        ShowCursor(true);
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        SetFocus(hWnd);
    }
    void run()
    {
        MSG msg;
        PeekMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
        while(running)
        {
            if(PeekMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                    running = false;

                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
            else
            {
                // Here, the draw function is called.
                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                Gdiplus::Graphics* g = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromHDC(hdc);
                draw(g);
                EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            }
        }
        UnregisterClass(ID, hInstance);
    }
};
```

And the main file (`main.cpp`):

```cpp
#include "Window.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

class AppWindow : public Window
{
public:
    void draw(Gdiplus::Graphics* g) override
    {
        Gdiplus::SolidBrush brown_brush(Gdiplus::Color(255, 128, 57, 0));
        g->FillRectangle(&brown_brush, 0, 0, 200, 200);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, nullptr);

    AppWindow w;
    w.run();

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

I have the problem that it just won't draw!

It handles every message, everything is good, but it doesn't draw. Even messages of type `WM_PAINT` are sent, but nothing happens.

Can you spot the problem?

I just want a window class that has an overridable `draw()` function with a `run()` function that handles all events, such as `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`. All of that works fine, the screen just stays blank.

Also, I can't close the window, when pressing the `X` button in the top-right corner, the window just stays; only after resizing and quickly pressing `X`, it closes.

As you can see, I have some pretty weird behaviour, and I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: You are calling `BeginPaint()` from outside the `WM_PAINT` handler. That is not allowed.

Comment: @rodrigo Ah, that was indeed the problem. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drawing logic is in the wrong place.  It needs to be inside the `MessageHandler` when processing a `WM_PAINT` message.  `PeekMessage()` will generate a `WM_PAINT` message if the window needs to be drawn and no other messages are pending.  You can't draw on the window from outside of a `WM_PAINT` handler.

Also, you are assigning the wrong value to `wc.hbrBackground` in `init()`.  If you use a color constant like `COLOR_WINDOW`, you need to add `1` to it.  This is stated as much in the [`WNDCLASS` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassa).

Also, in `run()`, your 1st `PeekMessage()` to create the message queue is discarding an initial message if one is pending, that message does not get processed by your dispatch loop.  That 1st call should be using the `PM_NOREMOVE` flag instead.

Also, be aware of [the dangers of filtering window messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493) in your message loop.

With that said, try this instead:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

class Window
{
private:
    HWND hWnd;
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    const char* ID = "WINAPI_JVM64";

public:
    Window()
    {
        init();
    }

    ~Window()
    {
        cleanup();
    }

    virtual void draw(Gdiplus::Graphics*) = 0;

    void init()
    {
        hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

        WNDCLASS wc{};
        wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = &MessageHandler;
        wc.hInstance = hInstance;
        wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_HAND);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
        wc.lpszClassName = ID;

        assert(RegisterClass(&wc));

        hWnd = CreateWindow(ID, "Title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                       200, 200, 400, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, this);
        assert(hWnd != NULL);

        ShowCursor(true);
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        SetFocus(hWnd);
    }

    void cleanup()
    {
        UnregisterClass(ID, hInstance);
    }

    void run()
    {
        MSG msg;
        PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);

        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
};
```

```cpp
#include "Window.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_NCCREATE:
        {
            Window *pThis = static_cast<Window*>(reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams);
            SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pThis));
            break;
        }

        // DefWindowProc(WM_CLOSE) calls DestroyWindow(),
        // WM_CLOSE is not the right place to call PostQuitMessage()...
        //case WM_CLOSE:
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            Window *pThis = reinterpret_cast<Window*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            if (pThis)
            {
                Gdiplus::Graphics* g = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromHDC(hdc);
                pThis->draw(g);
                delete g;
            }
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

class AppWindow : public Window
{
public:
    void draw(Gdiplus::Graphics* g) override
    {
        Gdiplus::SolidBrush brown_brush(Gdiplus::Color(255, 128, 57, 0));
        g->FillRectangle(&brown_brush, 0, 0, 200, 200);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, nullptr);

    AppWindow w;
    w.run();

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But I really don't know what happens in MessageHandler(): "case  WM_NCCREATE:{...}". Mind explaining that? And is ~Window() something like an "Anti-Constructor"?

Comment: Notice that I added the class object's `this` pointer to the `lpParam` parameter of `CreateWindow()`.  This way, the `this` pointer can be passed into `MessageHandler()` (which is not a member of the class) in the `WM_NCCREATE` (and `WM_CREATE`) message. I'm then storing the `this` pointer in the `HWND` itself for use with later messages, in this case `WM_PAINT` so it can call `draw()` on the correct `Window` object whose window is being painted.

Comment: `~Window()` is formally known as a [destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor).  I'm surprised you learned about constructors but not about destructors, since they go hand-in-hand together. The compiler calls a constructor when an object is being created, and calls the destructor when the object is being destroyed.

Comment: That's a fancy way of doing it, but can't I just create the window instance outside of `main()` and then access it in `MessageHandler()`? Just by the way: I started with C++ some days ago and did Java before that. But I did some research and understand what happens in `case WM_NCCREATE:{...}`.

Comment: @Lost "*can't I just create the window instance outside of `main()` and then access it in `MessageHandler()`?*" - you could, if you have only 1 `Window` object in memory at a time. If you ever need to have more than 1 `Window` at a time, that approach won't work anymore since they would be sharing the same `MessageHandler()`, so it needs to be able to differentiate between them. That is where its `hWnd` parameter comes into play, which makes a convenient place to store each object's `this` pointer for easy access.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. But when I tried your approach, nothing was drawn. It works when I put `AppWindow window` outside of `main()` tho.

Comment: @Lost WHERE the `AppWindow` object is created has no effect on HOW it behaves.  Did you step through the code with a debugger and verify that the `HWND` is actually being created, that `WM_PAINT` is actually being received, and that `AppWindow::draw()` is actually being called? If so, and you are still not seeing anything appear on your window, then something else is going on.

Comment: The problem is this: `if (pThis)` in `MessageHandler()` at `WM_PAINT`. It seems to be false every time.

Comment: I can't figure this out! So the problem is in `*pThis` being 0 in the first place, in `MessageHandler()` at `case WM_NCCREATE: {...}`. It is called but `*pThis` is 0 for some reason.

Comment: @Lost I tested the code I posted, it works fine for me. `pThis` is not NULL in either `WM_NCCREATE` or `WM_PAINT`, and I see a window with a brown area, as expected. Make sure you apply the code *correctly* to your project. For instance, did you update your code to pass `this` in the `lpParams` parameter of `CreateWindow()`? Your original code was passing NULL. Also, make sure your call to `assert(RegisterClass(&wc))` is not being optimized away, which would cause `CreateWindow()` to fail. You should save the return value to a variable and `assert()` on that, like I did for `CreateWindow()`.

Comment: That covers everything I wanted to know, at least for this thread. There are just two mistakes in your code: 1. In `class Window` in `run()`. One comma is missing after NULL. 2. It's `GWLP_USERDATA` not `GWL_USERDATA`.

Comment: @Lost fixed. Though `GWL_USERDATA` and `GWLP_USERDATA` have the same numeric value, so `GWL_USERDATA` would work, too.